# Visual Studio 2015 Select unity instance window empty

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2015

When pressing the 'Attach to Unity" button on visual studios, i get an empty 'Select Unity Instance' window instead of visual studios connecting to the unity editor and starting a debug session.

I've tried the following fixes from around the web trying to resolve this issue to no avail.

- Re-install Unity
- Re-install VS 2015
- Update Visual Studio 2015 Tools for Unity (V 3.7.0.1)
- Rebuild Solution files
- Checked Solution properties for debug and build
- Toggled between MonoDevelop and VS in unity's preferences (affects both VS 2015 & VS 2017 installs.)
- Can't run editor in Admin mode due to IT...
- Uninstalling the 'Get Xamarin' extension for VS
- Rebooted system multiple times
- Ensured that Unity.exe is still Unity.exe and has not been renamed

The odd thing is that this functionality used to work and i can generate builds and deployment packages just fine.

I'm targeting the UWP platform and HoloLens under SDK version 10.0.14393.0

Answer (score -2):

Download the UnityDownloadAssistant, once the Assistant has been installed select the Visual studio 2017 Community edition and install that, its free . Don`t struggle with 2015 versions of visual studio.

Comment: Enterprise policies prevent our multinational company from using the free community version. I also already tried VS 2017 through Enterprise licencing and have the same issue on both platforms. I'm using VS 2015 as we had numerous other issues with VS2017 and UWP, IL2CPP, HoloLens.

Comment: Which Unity version do you use? With newer ones you definitely should use VS 2017! We have no trouble at all using Unity 5.6 - 2018.3  with VS 2017, UWP and HoloLens...

Comment: What an answer... I've got VS 2019 Professional. What should I do? Download the 2017 Community Edition? No.